# slow loop on google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have a question about google maps markers and javascript.

i have a page that only has a div (map_canvas) that creates a marker when you click on it, and a textfield where you input the name of a marker and the marker starts bouncing ...

to keep track of the markers i have an array of all the markers added. The problem is that when it gets to 20+ markers the UI tends to become unresponsive while its looping...

here is the loop that i have, its inside a function that takes the marker id as a parameter

```
for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if(markers[i].id == id)
        {
            if(markers[i].getAnimation() != null)
            {
                markers[i].setAnimation(null);
            }
            else
            {
                markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }
        else
            markers[i].setAnimation(null);
    }
```

please let me know if this is a re-post or if i should provide more information ... this is my first question here!

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by the UI tends to become unresponsive while looping.  Does the bouncing stop or does the map not display, etc.

Comment: the map does not respond while looping... if you try to click and move around the map it would not respond while the loop is finding the marker

Comment: Are you resetting the map after setting animation to the marker?

Comment: Also, do you start with all your markers, or are you adding a marker one by one via some sort of interface?

Comment: it creates markers as you click on the map_canvas, i start with 0 markers, and add them as the user clicks on the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `id` as the index in your `markers` array so that you can access each marker directly rather than looping to find it. Once you have a "current" marker, make a note of which it is in order that you know which one to stop bouncing when you start the next one bouncing.

```
var lastmarker;
...    
if (lastmarker) {markers[lastmarker].setAnimation(null)}
markers[id].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
lastmarker=id;
```

Of course, the viability of this suggestion depends on the rest of your code, of which we know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding steps/breakpoints in your code, not sure what coding environment you are in.....if you are just using straight html I would suggest using firebug to step through your code using breakpoints as this will allow you to see the issue in  your code.  I am guessing it is code related.

If you have already done so, I am pretty perplexed on your issue as to why it would just stop working at 20 or more markers....if it is not code related I would venture to guess that it has something to do with Google's api as I have run into some real odd occurrences once you get past their maxes on certain things although I haven't experienced a max on marker placement before, I have done something like what you are doing but in asp environment with many more markers.